# Creating database in SQL Server (problem with relationships)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, database-relations, table-relationships

I need to create a database from a CiteScore file (the file contains 10 identical pages from different years). I already created it and added tables from this file and assigned a variable ID for the primary key, but I wonder how to create a relationship between the tables (the tables are identical, only the data is different).

I want to use this database to create a tabular and multidimensional model.

Link to the database file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P8H6g_xKIrY4qvjQxiNKENiquXwh7_g-/view?usp=sharing

[Screenshot of one of the sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvCVg.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> the file contains 10 identical pages from different years

Then add a Year column to the table and load all 10 pages into the same table.

Comment: okay, but after turning ten tables into one, will it still be the correct basis for creating multidimensional and tabular models?

Comment: Yes. Yes it will.